# Incorrect display of column names in singleton query teradata

Tags: sql, singleton, teradata

I am building a singleton query, which is supposed to return predefined data from the query. The idea is that `Name`, `Company`, `Department` are column names.

```
WITH
singleton AS 
(
   SELECT  1 AS x
)
(
   SELECT  'Name','Company','Department' FROM singleton UNION
   SELECT 'A','b','c' FROM singleton UNION
   SELECT 'D','e','f' FROM singleton
)
```

However, the following issues occur:

- The column names are with a `'` in front and in the back.
- The column names are repeated as values (and I do not want them)

[image]

Comment: Try to remove this "SELECT  'Name','Company','Department' FROM singleton UNION" and use Aliases as : "SELECT 'A' as Name, 'b' as Company, 'c' as Department FROM singleton UNION"

Comment: @VBoka - well, it works so I guess this is it. I was thinking of some trick with the singleton line,  `SELECT 1 AS x`, creating the columns somehow.